# White space dashed lines plot R

Tags: r, plot

I want to draw more then one line in a plot. Therefore, I am using `lty= 2,3` and so on. But in the graph there is almost no white spice between the dashed lines. Is there any way to increase the white space between the dashed line? Because now the lines are hardly distinguishable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lty` arguments of many plotting functions accepts strings of length 2, 4, 6, and 8 which then specifies the "on" and "off" lengths corresponding to each character.

Compare the lines from the following and play around with the argument to get the idea:

```
plot(c(1,2),  c(1.0,1.0), type = "l", lty = "29", col = "red")
lines(c(1,2), c(1.2,1.2), type = "l", lty = "99", col = "orange")
lines(c(1,2), c(0.8,0.8), type = "l", lty = "2947", col = "blue")
```

**Edit:** To elaborate a bit more. The first character defines the length of the first line *dash*. The second character defined the length of the line *break*. The third and fourth character defines the length of the next line dash and break, respectively, and so on alternating. The dashed pattern generated is then repeated.
Try e.g. with `lty = "12345678"` to see --- this should be increasingly larger line dashes and breaks.

Comment: Thank you, this will work for me. Playing around with the argument did help. Although, I due not fully understand the logic behind the string and the output. Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: Yes, but what if I need to make dashes more than 9 times longer than blanks?

Comment: I do not think you can specify that **exactly**. At first glance, it should be `lty = "91"`; but it does not look quite right to me. `"92"` looks more like it. Explore e.g. all combinations of 2 with `plot(1:10); for (i in 1:9) for (j in 1:9) abline(h=i+j/10, lty=paste0(i, j))`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the base plotting library. You can try changing the parameter **lwd**

Borrowing some code from this tutorial
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/

```
set.seed(331)

# Plot some points with lines
# Set up the plotting area
par(mar=c(3,3,2,2))
plot(NA, xlim=c(1,4), ylim=c(0,1))

# Plot solid circles with solid lines
points(1:4, runif(4), type="b", pch=19,lty=4, lwd=2)

# Add open squares with dashed line, with heavier line width
points(1:4, runif(4), type="b", pch=0,  lty=4, lwd=4)

points(1:4, runif(4), type="b", pch=23,   # Diamond shape
       lty=4, cex=2,  lwd=8,             # Dotted line, double-size shapes,  fattest line
       col="#000099", bg="#FF6666")       # blue line, red fill
```

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX5oj.png) to see an example of the output of this graph

Comment: Setting the lwd higher is not really an option for me since the lines lining close to ease other. Setting the lwd parameter higher makes the lines overlap.